# GKE + Istio ingress + cert manager

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio, cert-manager

i have some issues with ssl certificates that are use with my istio ingress:
i use istio ingress-gateway load balancer
when i created certificate with cert manager it was without any problem
the one things that i needed to do was only to create patch,
the ssl certificate work well period 3~ month.

My issues with that started after the period:
cert manager created new certificate with new expiry date
but istio didn't makes any reload to the new certificate,
which is mean that i need to reload it manually.

My question is there is any way to avoid from this process ?
i want to avoid from all the manually process,
without any manually patch, way that istio will knows about the new certificate
and create auto reload or something like that.
it's overall auto reload not something special.
i tried this but with no success:

https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/certmanager/

Comment: When secret is updated, the cert will be pushed. Since certmanager does it automatically, it will depend on how are you updating the Secret. 

Also, It will depends how you are creating the certificates, Istio just reads a secret, it doesn't care if you signed it yourself with openssl, typed random bytes into kubectl, or certmanager wrote it, etc.

Comment: yes, you right
but i have situation that i need to replace the ssl \ remove and add to istio-ingress.
all of it needs to create manually because the patch is't create automatically.
every cert renewal i have to create manually action.

Comment: My recommendation is to contact GCP Support, in order to analyze deeper your issue https://console.cloud.google.com/support